# Publish a release for an older version of the repo

Tags: github, version-control, version, release

I just noticed a cool feature of GitHub, the releases (github.com/user/repo/releases). I'd like to mark three different releases of a language I've written.

- v1.0 - a commit on June 17
- v1.1 - a commit 7 days ago
- v2.0 - a commit this morning

However, I can't seem to find a way to mark a release to be published with a commit older than five days. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [creating a GitHub :release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/), you need to have pushed first tags.

So in your local repository, [create annotated tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) referencing any commit you want (however old they might be), and push them: `git push --tags`.

Then you can associate binaries to those tags into a GitHub release.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/releases/releases_tag_version.png]

Comment: Thanks very much.